# MvvmCross: NotImplementedException calling EnsureFolderExists method of IMvxFileStore

Tags: windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I'm developing my first Windows Store App, using MvvmCross framework and I have a problem with images management. In particular I have the following simple ViewModel in my PCL project, and a Store project with a button bound with AddPictureCommand.

```
    public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    IMvxPictureChooserTask _pictureChooserTask;
    IMvxFileStore _fileStore;

    public FirstViewModel(IMvxPictureChooserTask pictureChooserTask, IMvxFileStore fileStore)
    {
        _pictureChooserTask = pictureChooserTask;
        _fileStore = fileStore;
    }

    private byte[] _pictureBytes;
    public byte[] PictureBytes
    {
        get { return _pictureBytes; }
        set
        {
            if (_pictureBytes == value) return;
            _pictureBytes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => PictureBytes);
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddPictureCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => 
        {
            _pictureChooserTask.ChoosePictureFromLibrary(400, 95, pictureAvailable, () => { });
        }); }
    }

    private void pictureAvailable(Stream stream)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        PictureBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        GenerateImagePath();
    }

    private string GenerateImagePath()
    {
        if (PictureBytes == null) return null;
        var RandomFileName = "Image" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".jpg";
        _fileStore.EnsureFolderExists("Images");
        var path = _fileStore.PathCombine("Images", RandomFileName);
        _fileStore.WriteFile(path, PictureBytes);

        return path;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the method **_fileStore.EnsureFolderExists("Images");**
gives me the an "NotImplementedException" with message: "Need to implement this - doesn't seem obvious from the StorageFolder API".
Has anyone already seen it before?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not implemented exception is documented in the wiki - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#File

It should be fairly straightforward to implement these missing methods if they are required. Indeed I know of at least 2 users that have implemented these - but sadly they've not contributed them back.

to implement them, just

- fork (copy) the code from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/File/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WindowsStore/MvxWindowsStoreBlockingFileStore.cs
- implement the missing methods using the winrt StorageFolder apis
- in your Store UI project, don't load the `File` plugin - so comment out or remove the `File` bootstrap class.
- during setup, register your implementation with ioc using `Mvx.RegisterType` - e.g.:

  ```
  protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
  {
      base.InitializeFirstChance();

      Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxFileStore, MyFileStore>();
  }
  ```

For more on using ioc, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control

For more on customising the setup sequence, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Could you explain a bit more about the third point (during setup...)? What do I have to do with the modified class  MvxWindowsStoreBlockingFileStore ?

Comment: Updated answer with a snippet

Answer (score 1):

Following Stuart's suggestions I've implemented the following methods for Windows 8 Store App:

```
        public bool FolderExists(string folderPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var directory = ToFullPath(folderPath);
            var storageFolder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(directory).Await();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Exception in FolderExists - folderPath: {0} - {1}", folderPath, ex.ToLongString());
            throw ex;
        }
        return true;
        //throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement this - See EnsureFolderExists");
    }

        public void EnsureFolderExists(string folderPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var directory = ToFullPath(folderPath);
            var storageFolder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(directory).Await();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            var localFolder = ToFullPath(string.Empty);
            var storageFolder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(localFolder).Await();
            storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderPath).Await();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Exception in EnsureFolderExists - folderPath: {0} - {1}", folderPath, ex.ToLongString());
            throw ex;
        }

        //throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement this - doesn't seem obvious from the StorageFolder API");
        //var folder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(ToFullPath(folderPath)).Await();
    }
```

The third method we need to implement is DeleteFolder(string folderPath, bool recursive). Unfortunately StorageFolder method "DeleteFolder" doesn't have a "recursive" parameter. So I should implement DeleteFolder ignoring it:

```
        public void DeleteFolder(string folderPath, bool recursive)
    {
        try
        {
            var directory = ToFullPath(folderPath);
            var storageFolder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(directory).Await();
            storageFolder.DeleteAsync().Await();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //Folder doesn't exist. Nothing to do
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Exception in DeleteFolder - folderPath: {0} - {1}", folderPath, ex.ToLongString());
            throw ex;
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement this - See EnsureFolderExists");
    }
```

or I should check if the folder is empty before to delete it if "recursive" equals false.
Better implementations are welcomed.